# Datepicker in Linq doesnt work

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

I have the following datepicker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
});
```

Linq:

```
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
        {
            trips = trips.Where(s => s.DateTimeDepart == Convert.ToDateTime(date));
        }
```

And the model of DateTimeDepart

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:f}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime DateTimeDepart { get; set; }
```

I get the following error when compile: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Any guidelines or solutions?THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input date format is "dd/MM/yy", so we need to specify the format before parsing.
Have a look into following example,

```
 public static void TestCode()
    {
        string dt = "16/02/12";
        List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            dates.Add(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-5 + i));
        }

        var foundDate = dates.Where(d => d == DateTime.ParseExact(dt,"dd/MM/yy",null).Date);

    }
```

Comment: get the error as well: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ParseExact(System.String, System.String, System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: It should work, can you make sure namespace **System.Collections.Generic , System.Linq** are used